# Laravel service provider is not found

Tags: php, laravel, caching, provider

When I access laravel, it said

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
'Krucas\Notification\NotificationServiceProvider' Not found
```

The Website locations is http://somedomain.com/index.php
It's document physical path is :

```
C:/Apache24/htdocs/new_project/laravel/public/laravel1/public
```

And I have these setting in

```
C:/Apache24/htdocs/new_project/laravel/public/laravel1/app/config/app.php
```

providers array  `'Krucas\Notification\NotificationServiceProvider'`

Alias Array   `'Notification'=> 'Krucas\Notification\Facades\Notification'`

How can I know the Laravel maps the provider array and alias array to the physical path?

Comment: Did you run `composer dump-autoload` from command prompt/terminal after you made changes?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71945107/7186739

Answer (score 25):

There were some cases with registration problem, cache issues, etc. Try one of these solutions:

- register your provider (in main composer.json, then in config/app.php [provider & alias] ), then run `composer dump-autoload`
- try `php artisan config:cache` or delete everything in `bootstrap/cache/`
- make sure you have initiated your package : go to the folder, then `composer init`

Answer (score 7):

After adding the dependency in composer.json, you have to install the package before adding the class in service provider, using the below command:

```
composer update
```

You can easily check if the physical file(NotificationServiceProvider) exists in your project. If it does not exists, you need to install the package using above command(don't forget to comment out the service provider declaration in app.php and re-enable after installing the package.)

Answer (score 0):

If you followed all the suggestions above and still have an issue, consider checking the case for your namespace, author name, or naming of your service provider. **It is case sensitive**, primarily if you are registering it manually in `config/app.php`

I had a similar issue, and it took me a while to realize it was a case-sensitive issue.

**Example:**

**Wrong:** `MyName\Something\SomethingServiceProvider::class`

**Correct:** **Myname**\Something...

So the problem was with **Myname** as it is case-sensitive.