# how to fix Service provider class not found when using repository?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to repository in laravel and trying to work on it , But when i run the application it throws the error

**Class 'App\Repositories\User\UserRepoServiceProvider' not found**

My interface and repository files are located in App\Repositories\User where Service Provider is also located

Here is my service provider

```
namespace App\Repositories\User

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class UserRepoServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider

{

public function register()
{

$this->app->bind('App\Repositories\User\userinterface','App\Repositories \User\userrepository');
}
}
```

Here is my userrepository.php

```
namespace App\Repositories\User

use App\Repositories\User\userinterface;
use App\car;

class userrepository implements userinterface
{

public function __construct(car $car){

$this->car = $car;
}

public function get($id)
{

return $this->car->findCar($id);
}

public function delete($id)
 {

return $this->car->deleteCar($id);
}


}
```

Here is my interface userinterface.php

```
namespace App\Repositories\User;

interface userinterface{

public function get($id);

public function delete($id);
}
```

I have also registered it in config/app.php file

**App\Repositories\User\UserRepoServiceProvider::class**

I did composer dump-autoload -o but no use. I cannot do composer update , when i do it throws the same error

Comment: Try deleting the cached files. `rm bootstrap/cache/*`. Then run composer install again.

Comment: May I know what changes it does to the application ?

Comment: Sure, first `ls` that dir to see which files will you delete. Those are cached versions that may have out of date contents. Plust, it does not actually change your app behavior. They will get regenerated automatically when needed. If in doubt just backup the files first.

Comment: No use , its still the same

Answer (score 3):

I usually check in bootstrap/cache/config.php for the package, sometimes after composer remove nameofthepackage, the package is still listed there

Answer (score 2):

You have to register the service provider in config/app.php.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers#registering-providers

Comment: I have registered it

Comment: Then it is most probably a problem with namespaces and the autoloading. Did you check the directory structure and the autoloading configuration in composer.json?

Answer (score -1):

I'm facing this problem Class 'App\Respositories\BackendServiceProvider' not found
It was due to spelling mistake in config/app.php file. I changed Respositories to Repositories and open this BackendServiceProvider and changed namespace also. so problem  has been solved.

```
Respositories to Repositories
namespace App\Respositories to namespace App\Repositories;
```

Answer (score -1):

**Working for me. You can try it!**

Remove "laravel/ui" reference and its provider from packges.php file.

[image]

Comment: type package.json